# Spacing rules for operatorname

Tags: spacing

When does extra space get inserted by \operatorname?
In the example below it appears extra spacing is inserted in the second and third case, but not the first. Why?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\operatorname{T}\{a,b\}\]
\[\operatorname{T}X\]
\[\operatorname{T}\big\{a,b\big\}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Last one should be `\bigl\{a,b\bigr\}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\operatorname` makes the command use the `\mathop` primitive to get operator spacing like `\log`.

TeX assigns a "class" to every atom in a math list and then adds space of various sizes between atoms of different classes. A mathop followed by an ordinary character gets a thin space but a mathop followed by a math-open (like `(` ) does not. This is so that
`\log x` gets a thin space separating the operator from the argument which is not needed in `\log(x)`.

Comment: There is a thin space in the last example because `\big\{` builds an ordinary symbol and not an opening.

Comment: @egreg, is it a bug? `\big\{` should be opening, shouldn't?

Comment: @Sigur no it's a documented feature, that is why there is a `\bigl` command.

Comment: @Sigur `\bigl\{` does `\mathopen{\big\{}` and `\bigr\}` does `\mathclose{\big\}}`. There's also `\bigm`, where `\bigm|` does `\mathrel{\big|}`. Economy is the only reason for the existence of `\big`, which should never be used.